# Detect Code Clone is not available in Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, code-analysis

Why detect Code clone is not available in Visual studio 2019?

[image]

I have used in 2017 but its not available in 2019, I try to modify the installation but its not available in the installer also.

Is that removed or its available somewhere?

I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019"

Comment: maybe it's only for enterprise edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In this blog](https://gowthamcbe.com/2020/05/14/code-clone-analysis-tool-in-visual-studio/) it says it's only for Enterprise edition.